# MATLAB using output of function into another function

Tags: matlab, function, nested

Not sure what Im doing wrong.  I am trying to use the result of the function crazyGrade into my new function GradeDist but I am doing something wrong.

```
 function [newGrades]=GradeDist(grades)

 newGrades=crazyGrade(grades) 
 % I want to take GradeDist(grades) 
 %and use the parameter grades to pass through crazyGrade 
 %and return it back to this function...but I cant figure that out...


 end
 % I want to use the output of this function in GradeDist
 function newGrades=crazyGrade(grades)
 newGrades=upper(grades) 
 newGrades(grades=='A')='F'; 
 newGrades(grades=='B')='D';
 newGrades(grades=='C')='C';
 newGrades(grades=='D')='B';
 newGrades(grades=='F')='A';
 newGrades(grades=='Y')='W';
 end
```

When I put GradeDist('A') in the command line .  I dont get any output.

Comment: is grades a string (which is an array)/cell array?

Comment: please post the error message, otherwise it is difficult to infer what is wrong. It is not obvious. Also include the input data

Comment: @AndreasH. When I put GradeDist('A') in the command line . I dont get any output.

Comment: When I enter it, I get something (unfortunately newlines are not displayed correctly): >> GradeDist('A')

newGrades =

A


newGrades =

F


ans =

F

Comment: Also note that you are never going to get "F"'s because of
newGrades(grades=='A')='F'; 
newGrades(grades=='F')='A'; 
;-)

Comment: You may want to use the debugger tool - 'set a breakpoint on current line' in the crazyGrade function - and see what you have

Answer (score 0):

I think because my filename was the name of the crazyGrader function when I changed it it seemed to work.  heres what i was trying to do if anyone was interested.

```
function newwGrades=GradeDist(grade)

newwGrades=crazyGrader(grade)



end



function newGrades=crazyGrader(grades)
newGrades=upper(grades) % convert the string to uppercase letter
% so it will be a string.
newGrades(grades=='A')='F';  % index the grades and replace the grades 
% according to the letter.
newGrades(grades=='B')='D';
newGrades(grades=='C')='C';
newGrades(grades=='D')='B';
newGrades(grades=='F')='A';
newGrades(grades=='Y')='W';
end
```